# Excel like filter in nat table header is reset on auto resizing the row

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

I'm using combo box column filter in nat table header.
On right click of row header "Auto resize row" option appears,after using this option to resize the row
combo filter is getting reset.However this does not happen on resizing the row ,in case normal text filter is used in nat table column header

How to avoid combo box filter from resetting on resizing the row?

Code snippet to facilitate auto resize of row:

```java
public void configureUiBindings(final UiBindingRegistry uiBindingRegistry) {

        // Mouse move - Show resize cursor

        uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstMouseMoveBinding(

            new ColumnResizeEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, GridRegion.ROW_HEADER, 0), new ColumnResizeCursorAction());

        uiBindingRegistry.registerMouseMoveBinding(new MouseEventMatcher(), new ClearCursorAction());

 

        // Column resize

        uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstMouseDragMode(new ColumnResizeEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, GridRegion.ROW_HEADER, 1),

            new ColumnResizeDragMode());

 

        uiBindingRegistry.registerDoubleClickBinding(new ColumnResizeEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, GridRegion.ROW_HEADER, 1),

            new AutoResizeColumnAction());

        uiBindingRegistry.registerSingleClickBinding(new ColumnResizeEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, GridRegion.ROW_HEADER, 1),

            new NoOpMouseAction());

 

      }
```

Code Snippet to add combo box column filter in nat table header

```java
public void configureRegistry(final IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {

          super.configureRegistry(configRegistry);

 

          // Shade the row to be slightly darker than the blue background.

          final Style rowStyle = new Style();

          rowStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, GUIHelper.getColor(197, 212, 231));

          configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, rowStyle, DisplayMode.NORMAL,

              GridRegion.FILTER_ROW);

        }

 

        {

          this.cellEditor = new FilterRowComboBoxCellEditor(comboBoxDataProvider, 5);

          ((FilterRowComboBoxCellEditor) this.cellEditor).setShowDropdownFilter(true);

          this.filterIconPainter =

              new ComboBoxFilterIconPainter(comboBoxDataProvider, GUIHelper.getImage("filtered"), null);

        }
```

Comment: It doesn't happen in the NatTable examples. So you should probably compare your code with the examples / default implementations. BTW, you talk about row resize and paste code for column resize bindings. Not sure what is correct.

Comment: Yes code snippet attached is for column resize bindings .@Dirk Fauth on adding HeaderMenuConfiguration to the nat table ,it adds context menu options to the column header,row header and also to the corner region.On right clicking the row header we get an option to auto resize row

Comment: My question is does this row header menu option resets excel like filter in nat table created using ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite?

Comment: Because in my case i've created excel column filter using ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite in the nat table.Nat table also has header menu configuration added.But when I click on row header menu ”Auto resize row";the excel like filter is reset

Comment: In case this the default behaviour in nat table what can be possible work around for it @Dirk Fauth

Comment: I am able to read. And my comments still apply. It does not happen in our examples from what I can see. So you should compare your code with ours. It should not reset the filter.

Comment: Are you talking about https://eclipse.googlesource.com/nattable/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable/+/7e6dd8788de1db341cb9d8d7b1db49622148125b/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.extension.glazedlists/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/extension/glazedlists/filterrow/ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite.java,.        you please share the link where I can find examples

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=examples_application

Comment: @Dirk Fauth     


Using customized ComboBoxGlazedListsFilterStrategy<T> excel like filter is getting reset on auto resizing row

ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite(

            ComboBoxGlazedListsFilterStrategy<T> filterStrategy,

            FilterRowComboBoxDataProvider<T> comboBoxDataProvider,

            ILayer columnHeaderLayer,

            IDataProvider columnHeaderDataProvider,

            IConfigRegistry configRegistry,

            boolean useDefaultConfiguration)

 

 

 

 
​

Comment: When I use following constructor like in the examples,excel like combo box filter is not getting reset on auto resizing row
Using default DefaultGlazedListsStaticFilterStrategy<T>

Comment: ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite(

            FilterList<T> filterList,

            ILayer bodyLayer,

            Collection<T> baseCollection,

            IColumnAccessor<T> bodyDataColumnAccessor,

            boolean lazyLoading,

            ILayer columnHeaderLayer,

            IDataProvider columnHeaderDataProvider,

            IConfigRegistry configRegistry,

            boolean useDefaultConfiguration),

Comment: Is it possible to avoid resetting of excel like filter when using customized ComboBoxGlazedListsFilterStrategy<T>

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with customized ComboBoxGlazedListsFilterStrategy. What is customized? What are you actually doing? There is no code that shows what you are doing! So how should anybody help without providing the necessary information?